# angular Tooltip not working on icons

Tags: angular, tooltip, angular-material

I'm working with tooltip from angular material. I want to show a tooltip when hovered on an icon. When I'm trying to implement angular material tooltip on the `<i>` tag, it seems not to be working.

module.ts

```
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatTooltipModule
    ]
```

component.html

```
<h4>Info <i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-xs" matTooltip="Info about the action"></i></h4>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried it on **<h4>** ?

Comment: yes, it is working only on <h4></h4> without icon in it. If there is icon, then it's not working

Comment: It might be due to the font-awesome CSS.

Comment: then, how would i be able to have this tooltip on icons?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: no errors. @Edric

Comment: I had the same problem with material icons (mat-icon).  I was able to wrap the icon in a span, put the matTooltip on the span instead, and it worked.

Comment: I have the same issue with mat-icon-buttons. the tooltip doesn't show up. Works great on block level elements. I tried wrapping the button in a span , but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some problem with Font awesome css or might material does support limited tags but try the below code.

```
 `<h4 matTooltip="Info about the action">Info <i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-xs"></i><`/h4>
```

Comment: Can you accept the answer and vote it up if it helped?